# passing parameter from build.xml to java file

Tags: java, ant, junit

when I run java test file(single file) through eclipse by passing arguments

> -DappRoot=ECM -DappName=ESW -Dapp.module=FNT -Dapp.env=LOC -DcloneNumber=1

test file executes without error, if I dont give arguments error occurs as Could not resolve placeholder 'appRoot'.

I have junit target to generate report in html format.

```
<target name="junit" depends="init-junit">
        <junit printsummary="on" fork="yes" forkmode="perBatch" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junit.failure" showoutput="false">           
            <classpath>
                <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/>             
            </classpath>            
            <batchtest fork="no"  todir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
               <fileset dir="${COMP_TEST_SRC}">                           
                  <include name="**/*Test.java" />          
               </fileset>              
            </batchtest>
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </junit>        
        <junitreport todir="${JUNIT_REPORT}">
            <fileset dir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />           
            </fileset>       
            <report format="frames" todir="${JUNIT_REPORT}"/>       
        </junitreport>          
    </target>
```

When I run above build script, getting following error: Could not resolve placeholder 'appRoot' where this has passed as an arguments.

I have passed parameter to build.xml through eclipse, this parameter passes to build.xml file but not passing to java files. How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**
tried with following parameter:

```
<junit printsummary="on" fork="yes" forkmode="perBatch" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junit.failure" showoutput="false">           
    <jvmarg value="-DappRoot=ECM" />
    <jvmarg value="-DappName=ESW" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dapp.module=FNT" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dapp.env=LOC" />
    <jvmarg value="-DcloneNumber=1" />
    <!--<sysproperty key="appRoot" value="${appRoot}"/>
    <sysproperty key="appName" value="${appName}"/>
    <sysproperty key="app.module" value="${app.module}"/>
    <sysproperty key="app.env" value="${app.env}"/>
    <sysproperty key="cloneNumber" value="${cloneNumber}"/>-->
    <classpath>
        <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/>             
    </classpath>
```

with system paramter it works fine but takes very long time to execute. with jvmarg it doesnt work. same error with

```
 <jvmarg value="-DappRoot=${appRoot}" />
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html doesn't define any restriction for sys and jvm args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of the junit ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) shows it:

```
<junit fork="yes" ...>
    <jvmarg value="-DappRoot=ECM" />
</junit>
```

If the appRoot property is passed as a system property to ant, you may access it as an ant property:

```
<junit fork="yes" ...>
    <jvmarg value="-DappRoot=${appRoot}" />
</junit>
```

Comment: u said If the appRoot property is passed as a system property to ant. what is the difference in system property and jvmarg?. which one is better to use?

Comment: a system property is a property passed through -Dproperty=value. jvmarg is simply the name that ant has chosen for arguments passed to the JVM. A jvm arg can be used to pass a system property (as above), but could also be used to pass something else (example : -Xmx512m, which sets the maximum heap size of the JVM).

Comment: 1) how can i set Xms and XmX values?    2) if suppose ${appRoot} is empty then i want to stop build and inform developer to set arguments and run. how can i do this?

Comment: 1) You don't have to. But you can using a jvmarg : <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />. 2) Ask another question. It's unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `fork="no"` in your `batchtest` element, which is overriding the `fork` setting in the `junit` element.  This is causing the `junit` task to execute in the same JVM as the ant process, which means the `jvmarg` parameters will be ignored.

I would also recommend using a fork mode of "once"; this will vastly improve the performance.

Try this:

```
<junit printsummary="on" fork="yes" forkmode="once" maxmemory="512m"
       haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junit.failure"
       showoutput="false">           
    <jvmarg value="-DappRoot=ECM" />
    <jvmarg value="-DappName=ESW" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dapp.module=FNT" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dapp.env=LOC" />
    <jvmarg value="-DcloneNumber=1" />
    <classpath>
        <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/>             
    </classpath>            
    <batchtest todir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
       <fileset dir="${COMP_TEST_SRC}">                           
          <include name="**/*Test.java" />          
       </fileset>              
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type="xml" />
</junit>
```

Note the `maxmemory` attribute.  Adjust the value as necessary.